# require() finding process.version to be undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm

I am trying to create a dashboard based off an existing dashboard template located below:

https://github.com/creativetimofficial/vuetify-material-dashboard

I am trying to integrate azure-storage into my solution in order to upload files directly to Azure.

https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-node

The following require statement is used to import azure-storage

```
var azure = require('azure-storage');
```

However I am getting the following error:

```
TypeError: process.version is undefined
```

I have tried reinstalling all modules as well as process. I thought that process was a globally defined variable, and I can't understand why version is returning undefined. What could be causing this issue?

Tried to debug by printing all properties of process and this is what I have:

[image: debug]

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like someone reported the same [issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-node/issues/516) on github.

Comment: Even process.versions which is supposed to return an array of all versions is returning undefined. I'm pretty sure there's an issue with environment setup but not sure where it could be. I tried to use azure-storage on a new template based off Vuetify/webpack, and the version is working properly. I have no idea where this could be coming from.

Comment: I've used a band-aid solution to resolve this by hardcoding __process.version = 'v9.40'__ in my application. It's working now, but this is definitely a bad solution. Would definitely appreciate input.

Comment: Are you importing this library into your client-side code? Because this lib has special builds for running in the browser, which you don't seem to use.